# About completion over a noetherian local ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ a noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $M$ and $N$ $R-$modules finitely generate and $\hat{M} \cong \hat{N}$ (the completion over the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$)  . I have that $\widehat{\mbox{Hom}_R(M,N)} \cong \mbox{Hom}_{\hat{R}}(\hat{M},\hat{N})$, but I'm stuck with to prove that, if $\phi \in \hat{\mathfrak{m}} \mbox{Hom}_{\hat{R}}(\hat{M},\hat{N})$, then $\phi(\hat{M}) = \hat{\mathfrak{m}}\hat{N}$. (Considering that $\hat{\mathfrak{m}} = \mathfrak{m}$).

Some hint or idea?

Comment: Did you mean $\phi(\hat{M})\subset\hat{\mathfrak{m}}\hat{N}$? If so, can you tell me what have you tried?

Comment: @Mohan I was trying using the fact that $\widehat{Hom_R(M,N)}$ is finitely generated and also is $\mathfrak{m}$. Now $\phi$ is a finite sum of the product of generator of the above objects. I think that is $\phi(\hat{M}) = \mathfrak{m}\hat{N}$

Comment: Try $\phi=0$, clearly one such.

Comment: @Mohan Well, but if $\phi$ is non zero? Sorry for insist but, I need the equality for another result.

Comment: No, still false and easy to construct them starting with the zero case. Think of $N=N_1\oplus N_2$ and $\phi$ zero in one of the factors.

Comment: @Mohan Oh I got it thanks, I'm trying to solve the problem 7.5 of Eisenbud's Book(Commutative Alg.) and this say that I'm trying to prove, can you check it out please? To understand what is trying to say ?